# jPlayer get current track using "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, this, jplayer

I'd like to get the jPlayer current track info using the `this` keyword instead of an object name.

I know I can capture the current track position like so:

```
var myPlaylist =  new jPlayerPlaylist({
  ready: function(event) {
     $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) { 
     console.log('myPlaylist.current'+myPlaylist.current);
  });
});
```

but my question is there any way to capture it using the `this` keyword like so (noting that the code below doesn't work):

```
new jPlayerPlaylist({
  ready: function(event) {
     $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) { 
     console.log('this.current'+this.current);
  });
});
```

Comment: It is idiomatic for the `this` value inside a handler to be the element. The second snippet looks confusing, even if it works.

Comment: @pimvdb, i can't use the `myPlaylist` because there will be multiple `jPlayerPlaylist` instances but don't know how else to access the `jPlayerPlaylist` object.